# Stripping tags in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a Rails application and I have question regarding stripping text for tags. Is it normal to use the `strip_tags` method everywhere the view is showing text that the user have submitted? Or should all input be validated in the model and then you don't need the `strip_tags` method in the view? It will be many places to add this and therefore I wonder if I am correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're working with Rails 3+, it automatically escapes everything outputted in views from Ruby. Nothing to do, you're safe by default.

If you're working with Rails 2.3 and down, use `<%= h some_var %>` to escape potentially harmful variables.

Also you could use the gem `rails_xss` with Rails 2.3 to add the protection from Rails 3

Answer (score 0):

I'd strip all tags on input / save and then you don't need to worry about it later. If you do want to actually maintain the tags then consider using the `Presenter` design pattern and just have all of your model data output go through its presenter, at which point you can strip tags in a single place.